# Want to make a multi page navigation menu "HTML, JS, jQuery, Bootstrap"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello i have been looking for a answer with no luck.

Im looking for a way to clean up my code by having a navigation bar that i can add to other pages with ease.

I have been trying hard to get this right but whitout luck. Hope i can get an answer here.

Im using the Bootstrap library and would be wonderful if someone out there would help me out.

HTML code you will find below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap 4 Layout</title>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,800">
        <link rel='stylesheet' href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        
        <!--Main Menu-->
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CompanyName</a>
        
                   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
                   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                     </button>
        
                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Products
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Product 1</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Product 2</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another Product</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

                    <!--Futured posts-->
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                        <h1 class="display-4">Simple. Elegant. Awesome.</h1>
                        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
                    
                        <p class="lead">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <!--Roster Cards-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                            <div class="card mb-4">
                                <div class="card-body text-center">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                            <div class="card mb-4">
                                <div class="card-body text-center">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                            <div class="card mb-4">
                                <div class="card-body text-center">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-sm-4 mt-md-0">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 text-sm-center text-md-left">
                            <h3>An important heading</h3>
                            <p class="lead">A sort of important subheading can go here, which is larger and gray.</p>
                    
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                        </div>
                    
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                            <h3 class="mb-4">Secondary Menu</h3>
                    
                            <ul class="nav flex-column nav-pills">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
        <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a template system (or an include system) that either runs server side (most common) or at build time (which can support HTTP servers which only allow static files).

Use whatever programming language you like (subject to support by your server if you are doing this server-side); PHP is as common as muck, Java is an option, I tend towards Perl (and more specifically: [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/)), there are many others. JavaScript is becoming increasingly popular for this type of job, with tools such as [assemble](http://assemble.io/) becoming available. You can go all the way with [a static site generator](https://www.staticgen.com/).

Use a search engine to find popular template languages or include systems for your programming language of choice.